# Joomla Seminar Component customisation

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

I am using the Joomla Seminar component , http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/calendars-a-events/events/events-registration/8426

I would like to retrieve the query to return the organiser's name, thus search the query across the component files.

I get stuck at this function :`$config = &JComponentHelper::getParams('com_seminar');`

How do I retrieve the SQL query from here? Any pointers appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get organiser's name by seminar number / code:

```
$number = "123"; // here the number to search
$db = &JFactory::getDBO();
$q = "SELECT name FROM #__users u INNER JOIN #__seminar s ON (u.id=s.publisher) WHERE s.semnum='".$number."'";
$db->setQuery($q);
$organisername = $db->loadResult();
```

You can change the query as your needs, for example searching by seminar id:

```
$q = "SELECT name FROM #__users u INNER JOIN #__seminar s ON (u.id=s.publisher) WHERE s.id='".$id."'";
```